# How to conditional format merged and regular cells

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that I want to add a conditional formatting, but the merged cells kinda of get in the way.

In my spreadsheet, I have the columns B,C,D and E where i'm using a formula in column B for when columns C,D and E are "done" column B gets a green background. The problem is, for some rows, columns D and E are merged.

This is the formula I'm using in column B

`=and(C:C="done",D:D="done")`

My desired result is: When the columns D and E are not merged, column B only gets the green background if columns C,D and E are "done", or else, it stays blank.
When D and E are Merged : B only gets green background if C and DE are "done", or else, stays blank.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best you can get is:

```
=OR(AND(C:C="done", D:D="done", E:E="done"),     
    AND(C:C="done", D:D="done", ISBLANK(E:E)))
```

which will work unless 4th row:

[image]

but you could pre-populate the whole E column with **`=CHAR(1)`** and then:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If E *always* has a non-empty value when D and E aren't merged, you can use that to check for when E is blank using [`ISBLANK(E:E)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290):

```
=AND(C:C="done", D:D="done", OR(E:E="done", ISBLANK(E:E)))
```

Otherwise, there isn't a way to test if a cell is part of a merged range without using a custom function, which is far less efficient, but could technically work with the assistance of a new helper column (e.g. column Z):

```
/**
 * @customfunction
 */
function ISMERGED(cellAddress) {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellAddress);
  return cell.isPartOfMerge();
}
```

Where column Z (or whatever you choose for your helper) has the following in every relevant row (assuming data starts in row 1):

```
=ISMERGED(ADDRESS(ROW(E1), COLUMN(E1)))
=ISMERGED(ADDRESS(ROW(E2), COLUMN(E2)))
=ISMERGED(ADDRESS(ROW(E3), COLUMN(E3)))
```

...and so on.

And then for formatting B, use:

```
=AND(C:C="done", D:D="done", OR(E:E="done", $Z:$Z))
```

**WARNING:** If you toggle between merging and unmerging, Z wont contain the correct values immediately, though, because custom functions only re-compute when input changes (and the address of the cell wont in this case).

---

### Update

Here's how you could compute your helper for the whole column downward, by row, by just putting the value in the topmost cell (ex: `=ISMERGED("E:E")` in cell Z1):

```
/**
 * @customfunction
 */
function ISMERGED(rangeAddress) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rangeAddress);
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var result = [];
  for (var i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
    var rowRange = range.offset(i, 0, 1, numCols);
    result.push(rowRange.isPartOfMerge());
  }
  return result;
}
```